# Download copy of file which updates on change

Tags: filesystems, files, remote

I am using my Raspberry Pi (Debian) and I store code on this server in which people have access to. My problem at the moment is, I can open the file using SSH and then compile and run the code on the Pi but this is very slow.

What I want to do: I want it so I can make changes of the file(s) on my computer and this updates with the files on the server and I can then compile the code on my machine AND I do not have to keep pushing the files back onto the file server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UNIX world more suitable solution is NFS. The control file is usually `/etc/exports`. Example line `/mnt/export   *(rw)`. You can mount share from client `mount nfs-server:/mnt/export /mnt/local`. For examine shared (also known as "exported") resources on nfs-server use `showmount -e nfs-server`

Comment: I am using NFS for the "TimeMachine" back-up, so I like the way you suggested. A question - Does this method require me to physically download the files on my laptop? I am using SSD's because I don't want to store anything on my laptop, only on my server. Thank you

Comment: No. The file actually stores on nfs-share. There is no any local disk usage.

Comment: Thank you :) Can you recommend a tutorial that can explain how to do this fully? This is exactly what I need.

Comment: I guess you should start from [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System#Typical_implementation) and [here](http://nfs.sourceforge.net/) is the quite authoritative source of nfs-related information.

Comment: afs is supposedly more robust.

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this. You could setup a [Samba server](http://www.samba.org/). This would allow multiple computers to see the same files without having to copy them back and forth.

If you have just `SSH` access you might want to take a look at [sshfuse](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html).

#### make mountpoint

```
% mkdir blah
```

#### mount remote directory through sshfs

```
% sshfs root@somehost:/root blah
```

#### see remote files, locally

```
% ls blah/
file1
file2
file3
```

#### unmount when done

```
% fusermount -u blah
```

More info on sshfs is available [here](http://www.debianadmin.com/mount-a-remote-file-system-through-ssh-using-sshfs.html).