# Can I Store the Output of FFmpeg to a Different PC?

Tags: linux, ssh, ffmpeg

I have a question about storing the output of a screen recording using FFmpeg.

Currently, I want to use the:

- `ffmpeg -video_size 1024x768 -framerate 25 -f x11grab -i :0.0 output.mp4`

command to grab a screen recording on a remote Linux machine, where I am connecting to the Linux machine using ssh on my PC.

I was wondering, would it be possible to save `output.mp4` onto my local machine after ending the screen recording instead of on the remote Linux machine? Or to a different location instead of the Linux machine in general?

I am new to Linux and using ssh, so I any advice is greatly appreciated!

So far when using this command, I have been able to change the path location for the output file, but am not able to figure out how to get it to save to a location other than the remote Linux machine.

Comment: Yes, sure, you just have to [map a remote directory to the local computer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62677/best-way-to-mount-remote-folder). There are tons of ways of going about it, but a pretty simple one is to use `sshfs`.

Comment: @EduardoTrápani also samba